# How to set environment variable for specific IIS application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, environment-variables, webserver, iis-10

I would like to set an environment variable that should only be available to a specific ASP.NET web application running in IIS 10. I came upon [Setting environment variables for asp.net core when publishing on IIS](https://www.andrecarlucci.com/en/setting-environment-variables-for-asp-net-core-when-publishing-on-iis/), but I have an ASP.NET application (.NET framework) not .NET Core.

I did try what they said to do anyhow:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Navigate to my specific web application under "Default Web Site"
3. Click on "Configuration Editor" under the "Management" heading
4. Load the configs from `system.webServer/aspNetCore`
5. Added my environment variable
6. Restarted IIS

From C#, I attempted to get the value of this environment variable using:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_HERE");
```

And it came back `null`. Even after rebooting my Windows 10 laptop I was still getting a `null` value.

**How can I set an environment variable so only a specific IIS application/virtual directory has access to it?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/environmentvariables/

Comment: @LexLi: I actually read that too. Problem is I do not want this part of our Web.config, nor do I want this set as part of a config transform during publishing from Visual Studio.

Comment: I wonder how much you know of IIS. 1) application pool settings never go to your `web.config`. 2) Such settings are set by server administrators when they create your web sites, so VS is irrelevant either.

Comment: @LexLi: I realize all of that. I was actually in IIS Manager when I added the environment variables to begin with, but they don't seem to be available from within the C# web application. Do I need to manually edit ApplicationHost.config maybe?

Comment: "I was actually in IIS Manager when I added the environment variables to begin with". How can that be possible? The article I pasted above clearly indicates that there is no IIS Manager UI to configure that and you either edit the config file or use some scripting.

Comment: The "Configuration Editor" in IIS Manager seems a little misleading then. I was able to add the environment variable to the application pool using `appcmd.exe`, but that seems to make the environment variable available to anything running in that app pool, which is now what I'm looking for. I think I'm trying to pound a square peg into a round hole, here. I think I'm using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: The minimal unit that read/write environment variable is a process. Therefore, it makes sense to set it only at process level (application pool). (The ASP.NET Core settings are used to initialize Kestrel processes, so that's also per process.)

Comment: @Greg Burghardt. did you end up resolving this? im having the same issue.

Comment: @rannirabadi: No I didn't. I was reluctant to put the settings in Web.config, because I wanted something a little more difficult to access, but so far I've been out of luck.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - I feel your pain. I was using Web.debug.config to handle environment variables for my dev environment. It was working fine actually, and then get this, I configured publish profiles for remote debugging and it STOPPED WORKING. 

I guess this is the kind of thing that happens when you have thousands of engineers over the span of 30 years work on the same codebase.